# Is there any passive form of “congratulate” with the preposition object as the subject?

Tags: passive-voice

Take “I congratulated Andrew on his birthday” as an example.
The passive form is “Andrew was congratulated on his birthday”.
Is there any structure like “His birthday was congratulated”, meaning there were some people congratulating him on his birthday?
If not, how can this be said?

Answer (score 1):

'Congratulated' can be used here, though the sentence formation will be a little bit different.

"On his birthday, he/Andrew was congratulated by his friends."

Comment: The Latin derivation of 'congratulate' means something like 'share joy with', so you can only congratulate a person, not an event.

Comment: That's a great add on.  I didn't know that. Thanks !! :)